# Render a directive from a controller

Tags: angularjs

I've built a directive `<playlist>` which calls my custom service to return and then display a list of videos. So far so good. However, I don't want this directive to render and call my API until the user clicks on a link *elsewhere* on the page.

How can I have a link outside of the directive trigger the rendering of the `<playlist>` item? I looked for some sort of onShow event to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ng-if directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) to keep your directive out of the DOM until the link is clicked. So your HTML would looks something like this:

```
<div ng-if="showPlaylist">
    <playlist />
</div>
```

Then you would just set `showPlaylist` to true when you want it to show/render.

Comment: This is great except that it seems ngIf deletes its scope when removed. `showPlaylist` will be a toggle and so it can be shown and hidden however I would want to call the API only the first time it is shown and then cache the results in the scope after.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out based on *dnc253*'s feedback.

```
<a href="" ng-click="showPlaylist = showPlaylist ? false : true">Toggle Playlist</a>

<div ng-if="showPlaylist != undefined">
     <playlist ng-show="showPlaylist"></playlist>
</div>
```

On initial page load `<playlist>` is hidden and not rendered. Clicking the link renders  `<playlist>`. Subsequent clicks toggle the `ng-show` attribute and so the scope is not reset.